# how to string match regex in c++

Tags: c++

how can I check if the string is matched with an expression using regex c++
(its for robots.txt parser)

```
eg:

string will be an url
http://www.google.com/example/e/se/in

/*/e/*
```

means i need to match with the url if it is present or not ....normal query like `/example/`
can be matched using substring but ..how can i parse some thing similar to this

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you taken a look at any existing C++ regex libraries, e.g. Boost (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/regex/)?

Comment: i tried this `  boost::regex reg("/*/a/*");
  bool b1 = boost::regex_search("google.com/asd/a/asd", reg);` but it matches `google.com/asd/aa/asd` also

Comment: You seem to be confusing shell globs with regular expressions.  `*` means "match zero or more of the preceding", not "match any string" like it does with globs.  Change `*` to `.*` in both instances.

Answer (score 3):

Regexes have no language support in the current C++ standard.  You'll have to use a 3rd-party library such as [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

The upcoming C++0x language standard does provide regexes in the `<regex>` header file, but the standard has not been finalized, and compiler support for the draft standard is limited.  Unless you're already developing code for the C++0x draft, I'd advise against this option to ensure that your code is portable.

Comment: This is incorrect with C++0x. `<regex>` has been implemented fully in VC++ 2010 and partially in GCC.